# Why my class is inaccessible whereas I have included the header file

Tags: c++

Could you help me understand why in these two strings I get errors: 1) C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*' 2) error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int.

```
MyString* m_pStr; // Link to a dynamically created string.
MyString* pPrev; // Pointer to the next counter.
```

**MyString.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "counter.h"

using namespace std;
class MyString
{
    char* m_pStr;   //String which is a member of the class.
    void CreateArray(const char * pStr);
    Counter* m_pMyCounter; // Pointer to its own counter. 

    public:
        MyString(const char* pStr = "");
        MyString(const MyString & other);
        MyString(MyString && other);
        ~MyString();

        const char * GetString();
        void SetNewString(char * str);

        void printAllStrings(); 
        void ChangeCase();
        void printAlphabetically();
};
```

**MyString.cpp**

```
#include "myString.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


MyString::MyString(const char* pStr){   
    this->CreateArray(pStr);
    strcpy(m_pStr, pStr);   
};
void MyString:: CreateArray(const char * pStr){
    int size_of_string = strlen(pStr)+1;    
    m_pStr = new char[size_of_string];  
}

MyString::MyString(const MyString & other){
    this->CreateArray(other.m_pStr);
    strcpy(m_pStr, other.m_pStr);
}

MyString::MyString(MyString && other){
    this->m_pStr = other.m_pStr;
    other.m_pStr = nullptr; 
}

MyString::~MyString(){
    delete[] m_pStr;
}

const char * MyString:: GetString(){
    return m_pStr;
}

void MyString:: SetNewString(char * str){
    this->CreateArray(str);
    strcpy(m_pStr, str);
}
```

**counter.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "myString.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Counter{
    private:
        MyString* m_pStr; // Link to a dynamically created string.
        int m_nOwners; // Counter of users of this string.
        MyString* pPrev; // Pointer to the next counter.
    public:
        Counter(); 
        //Copy constructor.
        ~Counter();
        void AddUser();
        void RemoveUser();
};
```

Comment: Neither of your header files have to include the other as is.

Comment: And you could consider having one single header (defining both `Counter` and `MyString`)

Comment: Boil your code down to a single "file" which demonstrates the issues.  There's a lot of fluff as it is.

Comment: Well, what's wrong with having several header files?

Comment: @Trst - It's very much ok to have several header files, but they cannot all include each other. In your case myString includes counter, which includes myString, which includes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference for others, these are the causes I typically find for this error:

- Cyclic include (yes, that's you this time). Header A depends on B depends on A. This means that when you include A first, B is included above it. B tries to include A above it (again), but the "pragma once" or inclusion guard prevents this. Result is that B doesn't have a definition of A above it, but won't work without => this error.
- Inclusion guard messup. You create new header files and many people have the habit of copy/pasting an existing header file. This new header file may have its inclusion guards forgotten to be adjusted. If that happens, there's an include but the inclusion guards will only let either the new or the old header file in, whichever is first. The end result is that in some files that include your new header it won't work and the class will be undefined. May linger for a long time, I've seen code bases that had this condition existing for years undetected. Not eligible for "pragma once" users.
- Actually forgotten to write the class / typos in use or definition / capitalization differing. Obvious problem, obvious solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have a loop in the include files. The compiler does not do an infinite recursion because you have added the `#pragma once` option.

Here is what the compiler does:

1. Read the CPP file. Find the `#include "myString.h"`.
2. Read the `"myString.h"` file, find the `#include "counter.h"`.
3. Read the `"counter.h"` file, find the `#include "myString.h"`, but ignore it because of the `#pragma once`.
4. Go on with `"counter.h"`, read the `MyString* m_pStr;` line, don't know what `MyString` is, fail with a less-than-useful message.

Now, the solution would be to add the declaration of each other class in the header files. That is, add the following line to the beginning of `myString.h`, just after the `includes`.

```
class Counter;
```

And the following line to the beginning of `counter.h`:

```
class MyString;
```

Now, with that declaration in scope but without the class definition, there are some things that you can do and some things you cannot do: basically you can only declare pointers and references. Any other use of the class will have to go to the CPP file.

And you can even get rid of both recursive `includes`!